# Как получить выбранный элемент в ListBox с помощью JavaScript?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Собственно как получить SelectedItem, используя JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
var list = document.getElementbyId("list");
var selected = list.options.selectedIndex;
```

или

```
var list = document.getElementbyId("list");
var length = list.options.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (list.options[i].selected) {
        // TODO: ...
    }
}
```